# SVG анимация линии

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Есть кривая линия. Нужно сделать плавную зацикленную svg-анимацию волны. К примеру вот такая вот кривая

```html
<svg width="1439" height="368" viewBox="0 0 1439 368" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M3.5 366C45.3333 297.5 213.9 191.2 553.5 314C893.1 436.8 1285 157.833 1438.5 3" stroke="url(#paint0_linear_13_66)" stroke-opacity="0.13" stroke-width="6"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_13_66" x1="1438.5" y1="3.86474" x2="3.5" y2="3.86467" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#343045"/>
<stop offset="0.348958" stop-color="#C0B7E8"/>
<stop offset="0.6875" stop-color="#8176AF"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#343045"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация svg элемента (движущийся пар над стаканчиком кофе)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1522349/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-svg-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подробности по анимации уже давал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1522349/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-svg-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5).

Что-то такое:

```html
<svg width="1439" height="368" viewBox="0 0 1439 368" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M 4 366 C 45 298 214 191 554 314 C 893 437 1285 158 1439 3" stroke-opacity="0.13" stroke-width="6" style="stroke: black;" stroke="black">
     <animate
      attributeName="d"
      dur="2s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values="M 4 366 C 45 298 214 191 554 314 C 893 437 1285 158 1439 3;
              M 0 186 C 175 309 370 479 671 219 C 915 8 1063 88 1439 366;
              M 4 366 C 45 298 214 191 554 314 C 893 437 1285 158 1439 3"/>
 </path>
</svg>
```

Убрал тут градиенты, которые всё равно никак не используются, убрал дроби, т.к. ни на что не влияют, принцип, думаю, понятен. Можно добавить больше промежуточных точек, чтобы анимация была плавнее, можно взять видео с волнами, и перерисовать кадры оттуда. Изначальная кривая у вас какая-то совсем кривая. Обычно волны это равнозначные синусоиды. Вообще волну не должно колбасить, [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LRc6k-clzE) вот есть объяснение.
Если повторять анимацию единичной волны из видео, то получится что-то вроде:

```html
<svg width="1439" height="368" viewBox="0 143 700 225" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M -300 300 L 700 300 C 837 300 805 243 852 200 C 886 169 936 282 1000 300 L 1100 300" stroke-opacity="0.13" stroke-width="6" style="stroke: black;" stroke="black">
    <animate
      attributeName="d"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values="M -300 300 L 700 300 C 837 300 805 243 852 200 C 886 169 936 282 1000 300 L 1100 300;
              M -300 300 L -301 300 C -164 300 -196 243 -149 200 C -115 169 -65 282 -1 300 L 1100 300;"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```